# Use PEAR-Package inside Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am writing an PHPUnit WebTestCase for a Symfony repository. In some tests I want to print out time measurements. For that case I found the PEAR [Console\Table](https://pear.php.net/package/Console_Table) package. Via Composer I get it installed, but how can I use it within my test?

The Console_Table.php doesn't have a namespace. So I think I could not use

```
use Console\Table;
```

or?

So when I must use the `require_once` statement, which is the right relativ path, when Composer installed the Table.php into vendor/pear/console_table/.

At this point I would say I am really new to PHP.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Just like `$table = new \Console_Table` using a backslash before the class name and `_` as *namespace* separator.

Comment: I tried, but does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
I get it. [absalon.valdes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044667/absalon-valdes) was right. `$table = \Console_Table();` is the solution.
Important was to do a clean build of the project in Eclipse. After that, the compiler recognizes the class.

My bad.
Thanks.